# Which TensorFlow Model version to use with each TensorFlow version?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using an old version of TensorFlow (e.g. v1.4). I would like to use the models in TensorFlow Models (https://github.com/tensorflow/models) but I'm not sure which version of the Models correspond to the correct TensorFlow version.

I would make a guess that v1.4 TF corresponds to v1.4 TF Model. But this assumption does not make sense for TF versions before v1.4, such as v1.1.

Anyone has any knowledge into this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question to myself.
It is hard to classify models at the moment precisely. However, I think I have the general idea on that.

We already have [Keras 2](https://blog.keras.io/introducing-keras-2.html) and we know
TensorFlow 2.0 is [coming](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/bgug1G6a89A):

> TensorFlow 2.0 will be a significant milestone, with a focus on ease of use. Here are some highlights of what users can expect with TensorFlow 2.0:
>
> Eager execution is a central feature of 2.0. It aligns users’ expectations about the programming model better with TensorFlow practice and should make TensorFlow easier to learn and apply.
>
> Support for more platforms and languages, and improved compatibility and parity between these components via standardization on exchange formats and alignment of APIs.
> We will remove deprecated APIs and reduce the amount of duplication, which has confused for users.

The rule of thumb I am using at the moment:

- I use `tf.keras.layers` instead of `tf.layers`. This is because Keras 2 will be the central part of the new TensorFlow 2.0.
- I assume the [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) are new if they use `tf.keras.layers`
- I enable eager execution often.